# change validation message bagisto

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vee-validate

I am using [Bagisto](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto) and want to change the validation message only for particular field

Code is as below

```
<div id="osAxisDiv" class="pres-select-form" :class="[errors.has('os_axis') || osaxiserror ? 'has-error' : '']">
                                        <input
                                            class="form-control"
                                            id="os_axis"
                                            type="number"
                                            name="os_axis"
                                            disabled
                                            v-validate="'required|min_value:1|max_value:180'"
                                            :data-vv-as="'&quot;Axis&quot;'"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="osAxisErr2" 
                                        class="control-error"
                                        v-if="errors.has('os_axis')"
                                        v-text="errors.first('os_axis')"
                                    ></div>
                                    <div id="osAxisErr1" 
                                        class="control-error"
                                        v-if="osaxiserror"
                                        v-text="`${osaxiserror}`"
                                    ></div>
```

The message shows now is

> The "Axis" field must be 180 or less

And want to change it. min and max validation messages are already in the language file but if I change that it will change for all min and max.

I have tried

in template file

```
 <div id="odAxisDiv" class="pres-select-form" :class="[errors.has('od_axis') || odaxiserror ? 'has-error' : '']">
    <input
      class="form-control"
      id="od_axis"
      type="number"
      name="od_axis"
      disabled
      v-validate="'required|min_value:1|max_value:180'"
      :data-vv-as="'Axis'"
    />
    <span v-if="errors.has('od_axis') || odaxiserror" class="error">
      {{ getOdAxisErrorMessage() }}
    </span>
  </div>

  <div id="odAxisErr2" class="control-error" v-if="errors.has('od_axis')" v-text="getOdAxisErrorMessage()"></div>
  <div id="odAxisErr1" class="control-error" v-if="odaxiserror" v-text="getOdAxisErrorMessage()"></div>
```

in vue

```
getOdAxisErrorMessage() {

      if (this.errors.has('od_axis')) {
        return this.errors.first('od_axis') || 'Axis values range from 1 to 180.';
      } else if (this.odaxiserror) {
        return this.odaxiserror;
      } else {
        return 'Axis values range from 1 to 180.'; 
      }
    },
```

the component is default `template`. This code is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

i don't use Bagisto but based on what you are trying to do i would try:

```
<div id="odAxisErr2" class="control-error" v-if="errors.has('od_axis')" v-text="hardcode the error or get it from the error object"></div>

<div id="odAxisErr1" class="control-error" v-else-if="odaxiserror" v-text="hardcode the error or get it from the error object"></div>

<div id="odAxisErr3" class="control-error" v-else-if="here-you-just-che" v-text="Axis values range from 1 to 180."></div>
```

clearly you have to make sure the if conditions are correct
as i don't think you can call a function from v-text.

If you want to customize the error message in the backend maybe [this article](https://bagisto.com/en/bagisto/) helps

Comment: The article you have shared related to server-side validation while these are the client side validations

Comment: Yes as you can see i wrote backend. The other part should work, just make sure the if conditions are correct, it is just vue code